# Copy summarized data from one table to another based on a some search criteria using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Need your help with the following query..

I have two tables:

Table1 = InvoiceTable
Table2 =  Group Table

Table1 contains the following columns:

TariffNumber, COO, Material Description, UOM, Qty, Unit Price, Amount, NetWeight, GrossWeight, StatisticalQty, Discount.

Table 2 contains the following columns:

HSCode, COO, Description, Qty, Amount, NetW, GrossW, StatsQty.

SEARCH CRITERIA:

IF TariffNumber and COO from Table 1 are equal then copy the same to a row of Table2.

Also, NetW, GrossW, StatsQty and Qty in Table2 should be the sum of the values of the summarized value of Netweight, GrossWeight, Qty and StatisticalQty of Table1 based on TariffNumber and COO.

For Example:

If data in Table1 is as follows

TABLE 1
Tariff Number   COO Material Description    UOM QTY UnitPrice   NetWeight   GrossWeight Amount  Statistical Qty Discount
81031000    CA      KG  10  100 10  20  1000    10  5
45678903    CA      KG  15  100 10  20  1500    10  5
81031000    CA      KG  20  100 15  30  2000    15  5
81031000    CA      KG  10  100 20  25  1000    20  5
45678903    IT      KG  5   100 30  35  500 30  5
81031000    CA      KG  25  100 10  15  2500    10  5
45678903    IT      KG  10  100 15  30  1000    15  5
81031000    CA      KG  5   100 10  20  500 10  5

Then the Output in Table2 should be as follows,

TABLE 2
HSCode  COO Description Qty Amount  NetW    GrossW  StatsQty

81031000    CA  ""  70  7000    65  110 65
45678903    CA  ""  15  1500    10  20  10
45678903    IT  ""  15  1500    45  65  45

I am not able to figure out the code for the same. PLEASE HELP !

Comment: How is this a JavaScript question?

Comment: I am actually working on a software called Flexicapture and can write codes only in Javascript. Data of Table1 is actually captured on its own but data in table2 needs to be extracted as per the mentioned criteria..

Comment: I'm not personally familiar with Flexicapture, and there isn't a tag already in StackOverflow so I'm guessing most people aren't familiar with it.  There really isn't much information in your question about what you are struggling with. Is there some way to frame your question in terms of what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: It's a comparatively new software. For starters, Can i know how to copy one   row of table1 to another row of table2 using javascript?

Comment: My issue is that the question you posed makes no sense from the perspective of a JavaScript developer (are you talking about two JSON objects or some query language written on top pf JavaScript?). It might make perfect sense to a user of Flexicapture, but that community hasn't established itself here yet.